# Why do I get these white artifacts when blending images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending, blend-modes, composition

I'm trying to blend a photo onto my render using soft light blending mode, but I get these white pixels. Never had this happen before.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was bugged. It fixed itself upon resetting photoshop